Align first row of matrix to equal sign
To please my teacher's psychorigidity I want to make my matrices' first row aligned with the equal sign and maybe operations than follow.
I found some answers that were not quite satisfactory and felt a bit hacky.
I however ended up with this command :
\newcommand{\topalignedmatrix}[1]{
    \raisebox{-\totalheight/2+0.7em}{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}
}

I simply raise the matrix by minus half of its total height and I have to add 0.7 em because I guess the total height also includes some margin.
My question is: Is there a simpler or more idiomatic way of doing that ?
Flaws: hardcoded 0.7em (thus maybe not very accurate), using raisebox to lower it and feels a bit hacky
Example :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,calc}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\topalignedmatrix}[1]{
    \raisebox{-\totalheight/2+0.7em}{\begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}}
}

\[

A = \topalignedmatrix{
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
} 
+ \topalignedmatrix{
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
}

\]
\end{document}



I guess it's useless to ask the teacher to find any good quality book (their own exclusive) where matrices are typeset that way.
Use nicematrix (requires a few runs of LaTeX when a matrix is added or modified).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
A = \begin{pNiceMatrix}[t]
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{pNiceMatrix} 
+ \begin{pNiceMatrix}[t]
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}



You could use the tabularray package and change the baseline of the matrix:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
A = 
\begin{+pmatrix}[baseline=t]
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{+pmatrix} 
+ 
\begin{+pmatrix}[baseline=t]
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{+pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}



Thanks a lot !!

@TummaLumi You're welcome!

A less hacky version.  While I know that you don't need \dimexpr with calc, I try to avoid bad habits.  Note that you lose math mode inside \raisebox.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,calc}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\topalignedmatrix}[1]{%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox-\height}{$\displaystyle \begin{pmatrix}#1\end{pmatrix}$}
}

\[
A = \topalignedmatrix{
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
} 
+ \topalignedmatrix{
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
}
\]
\end{document}


Thanks a lot, it is very interesting, how does \ht\strutbox-\height work ?
Does \ht\strutbox = the height of a \strutbox ? whatever a strutbox is
And what does \height refer to ?

-\height moves the baseline to the top of the matrix.  \ht\strutbox moves the baseline down one row (since array adds a \strut to each row).
